# Postgres как правильно построить связь?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

Помогите правильно построить связь.

Есть таблица в которой хранятся данные загруженных картинок.
1 строка = 1 файл.

Есть несколько сущностей в которых я хочу использовать эти картинки,
Товары, категории, бренды и прочее. 1 картинка может использоватся одновременно во многих местах(товар, категория и тд)

Использую nestjs + sequlize.

Попробовал в модели товара указать

```
  // product.model.ts
  @HasMany(() => Mediafile)
  @Column({})
  image: Mediafile;
```

Но ругается
Foreign key for "Product" is missing on "Mediafile".

Получается что нужно указать айдишник продукта? Но ведь тогда получается что картинка будет привязана только к этому товару?

Как мне правильно выстроить связь?

Comment: Такая связь называется "many-to-many" и описывается другим способом https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Получается что с каждой сущностью нужно будет связывать черед дополнительную промежуточную таблицу? Это норм? Я просто в базах данных не силен, только изучаю. Получается что в базе со временем может быть куча таблиц, и огромная часть из них просто промежуточные. Это норм подход? После монги непривычно

Comment: Many-to-many не так часто встречается. Но да, в классической rdbms каждая такая связь требует таблицу. В Постгресе есть тип `array` - он позволит избежать таблицы. Только я не знаю, если этот фреймворк позволяет работать с таким типом данных.

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~ARRAY.html